# Trust SSH server based on key instead of if key+IP match

Tags: ssh

Is it possible to make the ssh client not care what IP a ssh server is behind (and if a different server was behind that IP earlier) but instead trust specific server keys? (And maybe nickname those keys?) I use dynamic DNS and I have IPv6 privacy extensions enabled on some computers and am always getting asked if it think it's safe to connect. Another possibility is addresses assigned by DHCP getting assigned to different ssh servers and causing all sorts of 'key doesn't match IP' errors.

Comment: I should have probably also mentioned that I have a list of public keys for each of my ssh server on a webpage that is served over SSL, so I have an easy way to check if I actually trust a specific server key set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a nickname for your server in [`~/.ssh/config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/ssh_config.5.html), and turn off `CheckHostIP` for this server.

```
Host nickname
HostName example.dyndns.org
CheckHostIP no
```

Before you connect to the server for the first time, you can copy the public key out-of-band: grab `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` from the server, remove the `root@hostname` part at the end of the line, add `example.dyndns.org` at the beginning, and append the line to [`~/.ssh/known_hosts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ssh.1.html#contenttoc3). Optionally run [`ssh-keygen -H`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/ssh-keygen.1.html) to hash the host name (this is only useful if you're concerned about the privacy of that entry if someone steals your hard disk or your backups, which for 99.99% of people is useless because the information is present in some other nearby location anyway).

Comment: With the `Host nickname`, does that mean I can just do `ssh nickname` so get to it? If so, that's pretty neat.

Comment: @Azendale: Exactly, that's a general feature to give a nickname to a host name and a set of options (user name, boolean options, tunnels, …).

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` add the line

```
CheckHostIP no
```

However, this takes away a bit of the *Secure* in SSH, because any machine can hide behind the IP or DynDNS name you connect to.

Comment: This doesn't take away any security at all. The whole point of storing the host key is to identify the other computer. The name and IP address are not relevant for security when you have the host key. Removing the spurious messages is in fact a gain for security (spurious messages consume your attention, which is a scarce resource).

Comment: @Gilles: The [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man5/ssh_config.5.html) disagrees. Yes, you do not lose any security for connections where there is no well-known IP-to-host relation, in other cases you give up protection against DNS spoofing attacks (as stated in the manpage).

Comment: I don't know what passage in the man page you're referring to. If it's the description of `CheckHostIP`, then no, it doesn't say you give up any protection. With `CheckHostIP no`, the spoofer still has to obtain the server's private key, and if she can do that, it's unlikely that she can't also spoof its IP address anyway.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how DNS spoofing would be dangerous if I know I trust the key? I use public key authentication to login, which makes it so a malicious server couldn't get a password, but what if I used passwords?

Comment: Using public key authentication doesn't really protect your password, the server could MITM you and get your password when you `sudo` or similar.

Comment: @remram How can a server MITM me if I'm checking host keys? Isn't that the whole point of checking host keys?